# powershell - dynamic object properties readed from a txt file

Tags: file, powershell, properties

I have a question, example:

```
$myxml.SelectSingleNode('//space:XMIS', $space).provider.factories.property.resources[0].name;
```

I would like to read the properties '.provider.factories.property.resources[0].name' from a text file and assign them to the object.
Can someone help please? I have no idea how to do this dynamically.

Comment: Does you line return the value you want? You just want that to be made into a property of a new object?

Comment: I need to parse some XML files. I want to declare in separate txt which tags atrributes/values I want. So I want to read declared property set from txt file and assign it to the selectsinglenode() to get specified value. //sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Property names can be specified dynamically e.g.:

```
$date = Get-Date
$prop1 = 'DayOfWeek'
$prop2 = 'value__'
$date.$prop1.$prop2
```

So read in your dynamic properties from a file and assign each to a variable. This assumes that the depth of properties is the same.  That may not work. Another approach is to use XPath for the whole query and then define the XPath in the txt file e.g.:

```
$ns = @{space = 'http://some-xml-namespace'}
$xpath = Get-Content query.txt -raw
Select-Xml -Xml $myxml -XPath $xpath -Namespace $ns

Content of query.txt
//space:XMIS/space:provider/space:factorties/space:property/space:resources[position()=1]@name
```

The xpath pattern is just a guess given that I can't see the structure of your xml.